# Looking for Windows script to delete files older than 1 year

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

I need a Windows script to delete files older than 1 year with:

```
forfiles  /S /P "E:\" /M *.* /D -365 /C "cmd /c echo @path" >> "xxx_log"
```

I am not familiar with Windows scripting.

Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

If you plan on using windows scripts/batch file, but you are not familiar with them, I really recommend you familiarize yourself first, otherwise it may be dangerous to play with, especially when deleting in bulk...

Fist of all open a Command Prompt and type `FORFILES /?` to read through the help for the `FORFILES` command and `DEL /?` for the `DEL` (delete) command.

The complete command you are looking for is something like this:

```
FORFILES /S /P "E:\" /M "*" /D -365 /C "CMD /C DEL @path"
```

Where `E:\` is the top level directory, `*` is the wildcard you want to match (e.g. change to `*.bak` to delete only files with the extension `.bak`) and 365 is the number of days (the minus sign means delete anything older than 365 days).

Comment: As well as the invalid `/Q` option you had used _(now corrected)_, I would also advise that there is no need to use the `/M` option, as it's default is already `*`. Also, you may also wish to include some other options for your `DEL` command, such as its `/A` and `/F` options. Additionally, since the intention is to delete files, you should omit possible directory paths, using `@ISDIR` too. Example: `FORFILES /P "E:\" /S /D -365 /C "CMD /C IF @ISDIR==FALSE DEL /A /F @PATH"`.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the invalid /Q option you had used (now corrected), I would also advise that there is no need to use the /M option, as it's default is already *. Also, you may also wish to include some other options for your DEL command, such as its /A and /F options. Additionally, since the intention is to delete files, you should omit possible directory paths, using @ISDIR too. Example: FORFILES /P "E:" /S /D -365 /C "CMD /C IF @ISDIR==FALSE DEL /A /F @PATH". – Compo yesterday

Thank you for your answer. Can I use the day to replace 365 ?

FORFILES /P "E:" /S /D -"01/01/2020" /C "CMD /C IF @ISDIR==FALSE DEL /A /F @PATH"  ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have a script to delete .zip files more than 30 days:

```
 @echo off
 FORFILES /p "c:\respaldos" /M *.zip /D -30 /C "cmd /c del @file"
```

I hope this help you, for more information write in CMD FORFILES /?